# How to handle .NET MAUI MVVM Application Settings?

Tags: .net, mvvm, settings, maui

I'm building an application in .NET MAUI with MVVM and I am new to both things. While I've been able to build individual views with viewmodels, I have a problem I'm not quite sure how to solve.

I have a configuration file in XML that I have loaded into an ojbect (model) and this needs to be used to populate a settings view. Any changes made to the settings in that view need to be able to be accessed by the other pages for various tasks.

I'm not sure how to go about making everything accessible to the other pages. Another problem I'm coming up against is that the Settings page is not the first page that is opened upon application start. So what I need to have is the default values loaded from the xml file at startup, unless changes have been made in the settings view, in which case I'll need those instead.

What's the best way to approach this design? Seems like I need a way to persist the settings data across all views with the settings view able to make changes to the values.

Comment: you can make your settings class a singleton, or add it as a property to your App class so that it is accessible throughout the app.  Your Settings class can also read the default values from the XML file if there is no user defined settings available

Comment: Do you need this xml file changed, after changes in the settings page are made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a configuration file in XML that I have loaded into an ojbect
> (model) and this needs to be used to populate a settings view.

For this, you can create a static global class for your setting. And you can access  and update these parameters across your app.

For example:

```
public class AppSetting 
{
    public static string Parameter1 = " parameter1";
    public static string Parameter2 = " parameter2";
}
```

Then in other places of your app, you can access and update your setting as follows:

```
        //access the global variable 
        string value1 = AppSetting.Parameter1;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("access the value of mParameter1 : " + value1);

        //update the value of the setting parameter
         AppSetting.Parameter2 = "reset value for test";
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("the updated value of Parameter2 " + AppSetting.Parameter2);
```